# Launch image for custom url - storyboard or asset catalog

Tags: ios, iphone, launchimage, uilaunchimagefile

I'm trying to have a custom launch image when a custom url launches the app. Is there a way to specify either a custom storyboard (UILaunchStoryboardName) or image from the asset catalog to use in this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible as of iOS 8.3

Comment: That was my fear, since there's nothing in the docs. Can I still use the previous way of specifying these custom launch images while also using a storyboard for the standard launch image?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to achieve this on iOS 8.3? I'm using LaunchScreen.xib for the standard launch screen. Is there a way to specify the launch images for a custom URL scheme, I can't seem to get it to work!